# Laravel Excel how to use second row as collection attributes

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-excel

I am using [Maatwebsite's Laravel-Excel package](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs). I want to import an Excel file, have laravel-excel ignore the first row, and use the second row as the collection attributes (table columns).

Without resorting to "import by config", is this possible?

It seems something like this [has not yet been implemented](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/259). I haven't dug into the source code for laravel-excel as it's a bit daunting to me, but is there some hard-coded value I could change so it starts at row 1 (instead of 0) and uses that one for the attribute names?

Comment: It's not yet implemented in my understanding. I guess most of the people fall in to first row as header and second row as content. or no header at all.

Comment: Mhmm. For now then, I will just delete the first row before importing.

Comment: Yeah, that make sense in a readability perspective too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this reference .

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/458

Set Config::set('excel.import.startRow', $headerRowNumber); in Config/excel file

Then use Config in your controller.